# how to use multithreading to load and render in android studio at the same time?

Tags: android, multithreading, loading

I am doing a loading screen in android studio, and I hope to render the animation(assets already loaded previously) and load new assets at the same time. Can I do this with multithreading?

Comment: yes you can do that with multithreading

Comment: Yes... But what I mean is... how?

Comment: you can read [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000025) about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `AsyncTask` if you want to load new assets in the background and return them to foreground. You can see how to use AsyncTask on official Android website:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can check out my article on how to use `AsyncTask`s in Android if you like to see it in action.

https://medium.com/@cepgamer/how-to-download-and-save-picture-aka-how-to-implement-custom-java-subscribers-13095f70eb84